# Is there a way to assign an alias to the Remote-Item Cmdlet's -Force parameter?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I would like to use the `Remove-Item` in a similar manner to how it is used in Unix/Linux:

```
PS> rm -r -f <the_directory>
```

However, this syntax produces an error:

> Remove-Item : Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name
>   'f' is ambiguous. Possible matches include: -Filter -Force.

Is there a way to assign an alias to the Remote-Item Cmdlet's -Force parameter (in my profile)?

Comment: First I would point out that all you need to do is add an o (-fo) to disambiguate it. Second I would say that aliasing a parameter would break autocomplete even if it were possible to alias a parameter. Third I would say that is typing that one letter is an onerous burden, I think the right solution would be to put a function in your profile that does rm using the full (or at least disambiguated) parameters then alias that as something like rmf.

Comment: @EBGreen, I wasn't aware of the disambiguation technique--that should suffice.